# PDFMake can't open the pdf file by send with binary

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

I'm writing the code with example of PDFMake but when i click for running the code it works but can't show the document.

Error message was showed in page of Google Chrome: **Unable to load PDF document.**

server.js

```
router.get('/welfare_pdf', (req, res, next) => {   
    var docDefinition = {
        content: ['pdfmake (since it\'s based on pdfkit) supports JPEG and PNG format']
    };

    createInvoice(docDefinition,function (binary){
        res.contentType('application/pdf');
        res.send(binary);
        }, function (error) {
            res.send('ERROR: ' + error);
        });
});
```

createInvoice.js

```
function createInvoice(pdfDoc, callback, res) {
   var fontDescriptors = {
        Roboto: {
            normal: path.join(__dirname + '/../route/font/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
            bold: path.join(__dirname, '..', '/font/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
            italics: path.join(__dirname, '..', '/font/Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
            bolditalics: path.join(__dirname, '..', '/font/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf')
        }   
    };
    
    var printer = new pdfMake(fontDescriptors);
    var doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfDoc);

    var chunks = [];
    var result;

    doc.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    doc.on('end', function () {
        result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        callback('data:application/pdf;base64,' + result.toString('base64'));
    });

    doc.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is two ways:

1. Binary

In callback return just base64 `callback(result.toString('base64'));`

then open as pdf file in client-side

```
printPDFFromServer(pdfBase64String: string): void {
    const raw = window.atob(pdfBase64String);
    const array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));
    for (let i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([array], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(fileURL);
}
```

2. Blob

just return without coding

```
router.get('/any', function (req, res) {
    const dd = { content: [{ text: 'TEST' }] };

    const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd, { autoPrint: true });
    res.contentType('application/pdf');
    pdfDoc.pipe(res);
    pdfDoc.end();
});
```

and open on client-side

```
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
```